# Using nginx and Drupal, how do I serve a 404 error for static files and directories that exist?

Tags: nginx, git, drupal, security, http-status-code-404

I deploy a Drupal web site using git (well, OK, the developers deploy it; I try to keep them out of trouble), and for that reason the site has a directory `.git` and a file `.gitignore` in the document root.

Currently the permissions on the files are sufficient to cause nginx to return a 403 Forbidden error if these files are accessed in the web browser.

However, I would like nginx to completely deny the existence of this file and directory, and return 404 if someone tries to access them in the browser.

But wait, there's more!

What I *really* want to happen is for the browser to receive the 404 error page generated by Drupal. In Drupal's `admin/settings/error-reporting` page, I see that 404 errors are being sent to http://www.example.com/`404error`, a Drupal node with one of the Internet's more interesting 404 pages.

My nginx configuration already contains a `@drupal` block which passes a request to Drupal. So I want to pass the request to Drupal, but I don't want Drupal to try to serve the existing static file either, but to simply serve the 404 page.

```
location @drupal {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$        /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

Unfortunately, Google hasn't been too helpful here; most people seem to have the opposite problem. How do I cause requests for anything in the `.git` directory or the `.gitignore` file to be sent to Drupal's 404 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a location block for the `.git` directory and set it to be [internal](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal). This should trigger 404 responses for any requests. If these aren't passed on to Drupal you may then need to define an [error_page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) to do so.

```
location /.git {
    internal;
}
error_page 404 /notfound;
```

The other option is to just rewrite those requests to something nonexistent:

```
rewrite ^/.git /notfound;
```